# Generate array of months back from 5 years until now

Tags: javascript

How to simply generate an array containing data like: `['Jul 2016', 'Aug 2016', 'Sep 2016', ..., 'Jun 2021', 'Jul 2021']`?

Started with this:

```js
const today = new Date()
// Tue Jul 20 2021 08:24:30 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

to run into troubles just a moment after:

```js
let past5 = new Date()
past5.setDate(past5.getFullYear() - 5, past5.getMonth(), past5.getDay())
// Wed Jan 06 2027 08:48:02 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) // ???
```

So, ended up with two problems:

1. How to get the correct date in the past (5 years ago), and
2. How to split the range into months.

Using `past5.getYear()` gives unreliable results as well...

EDIT:
This piece of code solves problem #1:

```js
past5.setFullYear(past5.getFullYear() - 5)
// Wed Jul 20 2016 09:00:03 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) `setDate` sets the *day of the month*  in a `Date` object. So you are setting the day to `2016` which in JS date arithemetic results in the date you are seeing. The simplest would be `past5.setFullYear(past5.getFullYear() - 5)`

Comment: Yes, I just found out that as well, and added to the question for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with changing date objects, this can be done with just integer logic combined with a list of month names:

```js
let monthNames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

let past5 = new Date();
let currentMonth = past5.getMonth();
let currentAbsMonth = past5.getFullYear() * 12 + currentMonth;
let allMonths = Array.from({length:12*5+1}, (_, offset) => 
    currentAbsMonth - 12*5 + offset
);

let result = allMonths.map(absMonth =>
    monthNames[absMonth % 12] + " " + Math.floor(absMonth / 12) 
);
             
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note: I had to update the snippet after it was accepted as it had a logical mistake. Please use updated version.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the year to months and subtract each month from the current date.

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

function getMonths(yrs) {
  let monthArr = []
  let months = yrs * 12;
  while (months > 0) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - (months - 1));
    monthArr.push(`${monthNames[d.getMonth()]}${d.getFullYear()}`)
    months--;
  }
  return monthArr;
}
console.log(getMonths(5))
```